# Replacing the contents of a specific id tag of an html string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, iframe, codemirror

I have a JS string like this:

```
var html_string = "<h3 id='title'>ABC</h3><h5 id='subtitle'>XYZ</h5>";
```

This string is then put into an CodeMirror iframe that makes it visible. I want to let the user change the Title and the Subtitle in a easy way with `<input>` fields. **How can I replace these specific texts using the id tags?**

For example if Title Input is "Hello", Subtitle Input is "World" and the current string is like the one shown above the new string should become:

```
"<h3 id='title'>Hello</h3><h5 id='subtitle'>World</h5>"
```

**Should I use a RegEx? What is the structure of a regex that does something like this?**

Note that I can't simply do a `replace("ABC", "Hello")` I need to change text based on the ID of the tag.

Comment: How are you getting the user input for title?

Comment: With an <input></input>, or just any other component like a text area. @hjpotter92

Answer (score 0):

for multiple you can use class, not id

```
$("h3.title").each(function(index){
    if($(this).text()=="Hello"){
        $("h5.subtitle:eq("+index+")").replace("XYZ",$("input#ID").val());
    }
})
```

Comment: Perhaps you missed ***How can I replace these specific tags***. There is no jQuery tag nor is it mentioned in the question, so you should not provide a jQuery dependent answer (guessing that *$* is *jQuery*).

Comment: sorry  $("h5.subtitle:eq("+index+")").replace("XYZ",$("input#ID").val())

Comment: I don't know beforehand the text "ABC" therefore I can't simply use a replace... I need to change the next using the ID of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

After rendering the HTML string into the page, replace the text using id of a tag, as shown in the sample code below:

```
$('#title').html("Hello");
$('#subtitle').html("World");
```

OR

If you know the old content and new content, then use the replace function like below.

```
html_string .replace("ABC", "Hello");
html_string .replace("XYZ", "World");
```

Comment: I believe none of the 2 solutions can actually work here sorry, I can't use the first one because the string wouldn't be changed, the important part here is the string. The second relies on the content of the string not on the id of the tag to replace the text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use a regular expression. Assuming the structure of `html_string` is predictable as in the example (title is always in `<h3>`, subtitle is always in `<h5>`, no additional attributes, always uses single quotes, etc), your code can be as simple as this:

```
html_string = html_string.replace( /(<h3 id='title'>).*?(</h3>)/, "$1New Text$2" );
html_string = html_string.replace( /(<h5 id='subtitle'>).*?(</h5>)/, "$1New Text$2" );
```

If the `title` and `subtitle` IDs might fall in different tags, or if the tags contain additional attributes, or if the IDs might fall in double quotes rather than single quotes, you'll need to modify the regular expression to find and handle such contingencies.

Regular expressions are not well-suited to parsing of complex HTML -- but they're a very good solution to the problem you've laid out here.